# Serve Utilization tools/report

Tags: windows-server-2003

We have 4 win2k3 servers and would like to plan for virtulization. I need to know the utilization of each server. Windows give the utilization from task manager window but I would like to know if there are any other tools/ways to find out (probably gives you some reports) about server ulitization?

Thank you in advance for any comments...
Hemal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each virtualization vendor has tools to do this.  If you're going with Hyper-V, Microsoft has the Microsoft Assessment and Planning (MAPS) toolkit, which gathers this information.  From VMware, some basic info metrics can be gathered using the Guided Consolidation feature within vCenter.  If you want more in depth metrics, you can hire a VMware partner to perform a Capacity Planner.  If you don't wish to hire someone, I would use the MAPS.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb977556.aspx

Comment: Amargeson,

Thank you very much for your input. I am going to find that out with MAPS..